# load model data in asp.net mvc3 by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code to search someone in my database :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#search').click(function () {
            $mvc.jssearchNational.search({ nationalCode: $("#karkonan_MelliCode").val() }).success(function (data) {
                $("#searchres").replaceWith("<span id=searchres>" + data.message + "</span>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want after the successful search, load person info in page by jquery. is it anyone to bind model dynamically and refresh the page by jquery or I have to assign each field to my page's controls?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bindings, try taking a look at the MVVM pattern and [KnockOutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)